# Boost PFC Control

Tags: control, boost, power-factor-correction

I am learning the Boost PFC control, and I read this [Master thesis](https://web.wpi.edu/Pubs/ETD/Available/etd-071416-063806/unrestricted/zliu.pdf) and I have some questions I want to ask you guys.

1.)In the PFC control why we need to multiple 1/x^2, can someone tell me? I think this question for a long time, my classmate told me you just remember this, I want to know why, can someone use math to tell me why?
[image]

2.)Can someone suggest a book talk about basic Boost PFC control? I search for some papers but the control is too complicated, I want to learn from the begining.

Comment: Take a look at p.19 of [this book](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/HBD853-D.PDF).